# htaccess, Redirect all others except your domain

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following Htaccess file that redirects all other traffic except my ip.

**How can I edit this to use a domain like dyndns instead since my ISP changes my IP?**

*Working Code*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^111.222.333.444
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com [R=302,L]
```

*Non-working Code*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^myDomain.dyndns.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.anothersite.com [R=302,L]
```

****Edit: It appears that with my webhost this is impossible (at the time of posting) however, This can be accomplished with some simple php code that I will include below.**

Comment: I'm also open to using my index.php file to make this happen if that's easier but I wouldn't know what code to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [htaccess: Allow from domain name instead of IP/subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376037/htaccess-allow-from-domain-name-instead-of-ip-subnet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My End soultion was to insert the following code into my index.php page

```
 <?php
    $ip = gethostbyname('myDomain.DynDns.com');
    if( $ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) 
        header("Location: http://example.com/ifLocalIpAddressSite");
    else 
    header("Location: http://example.com/IfExternalIpAddressSite");
    ?>
```